# Umbraco - use HTTPS for some pages

Tags: ssl, https, umbraco

I'm building a site with Umbraco, and there are a couple of pages that need to be visited over HTTPS instead of HTTP (e.g. a login page).

I've seen a couple of macros that get put on the page that needs to use HTTPS, and essentially just check the protocol used and do a `Response.Redirect` with the correct protocol if necessary. This seems like a terrible way of achieving what seems to be a fairly basic requirement - ideally I'd want Umbraco to render any links to these pages as `<a href="https://..."`, not do a redirect when the user goes to a page.

With these redirecting macros, there's also the possibility of a browser displaying a warning if the user's on an HTTPS page and navigates to a HTTP one. If the links are relative, the user will be redirected from HTTPS to HTTP, and the browser may warn about this.

Is there a way to achieve this without modifying any Umbraco framework code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no built-in way to make a few pages in Umbraco return a https url.

The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is just by making sure that you set up your links correctly.

But there's no way of stopping people from entering the insecure link. That is where the redirects come in handy though, it will make sure you don't get to a secure page insecurely.

I would recommend running the whole site in https mode. In the past, performance would have been an objection to running your full site in https mode. However with modern servers, this really shouldn't be a problem any more.

Comment: Ok, maybe the approach of using the redirect module as a backup for links set up in Umbraco isn't too bad. But running the whole site in HTTPS seems to make sense too. Thanks!